# Why is on form submit default value deleted?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery validation plugin, and after I added `focus()` and `blur()`event handlers to delete and set pre populated value,if I try to submit form without changing default value, value is replaced with empty string, where desired is to leave value untouched and run `validate()`.

JS code is as follows:

```
$.validator.addMethod("mobileHR", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\(|\)|\s+|-/g, "");
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^\+[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,14}$/);
}, "Unesite broj u fromatu: +385.111234567");


$(document).ready(function () {
    // append help block below input
    $('.controls').append('<span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">Format broja: +385.11123456789</span>');

    // clear pre populated value on focus 
    var value = $("input[name='contactdetails[Registrant][Phone]']").val();

    $("input[name='contactdetails[Registrant][Phone]']").focus(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == value)
        {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    }).blur(function(event) {
        if($(this).val() == "")
        {
            $(this).val(value);
        }
    });

    // initialize validation
    $('.form-horizontal').validate({ 
        // set immediate validation, on event code 9
        onkeyup: function (element, event) {
            if (event.which === 9 && this.elementValue(element) === "") {
                return;
            } else {
                this.element(element);
            }
        },
        rules: {
            "contactdetails[Registrant][Phone]": {
                required: true,
                mobileHR: true
            }
        },
        messages: {
            "contactdetails[Registrant][Phone]": {
                required: "Molimo unesite broj telefona"
            }
        }
    });

    // check if form is valid then enable submit button
     $('.form-horizontal input').on('keyup blur', function () {
        if ($('.form-horizontal').valid()) {
            $('.btn-primary').removeClass('btn-disabled');
        } else {
            $('.btn-primary').addClass('btn-disabled');
        }
    });

    //do we valid form on document.ready?
    //$('.form-horizontal').valid();

});
```

Fiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/AlanKis/wv0vrk10/4/).

Comment: `what is firing required() function instead warning user and leaving default, pre populated value in input box.` This line does not make sense in your question. Can you please edit it, and reword it so I can understand the question you're trying to ask.

Comment: @FrankerZ, see edit. Problem is that value is changed to empty string on form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After little research, I've found why is value changing on form submit:

```
$("input[name='contactdetails[Registrant][Phone]']").focus(function() {...});
```

After form is submitted, `validate()` is run, and as field is empty, input field is focused, so focus() is triggered again, and value of input field is `""`.

Changing event to `click` input field get focused, but value is untouched, as now function is fired on click event.